# Why does Redshift UNLOAD query is not able to quote column correctly?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have following row in AWS Redshift warehouse table.

```
name               
-------------------
tokenauthserver2018
```

This I queried via simple `SELECT` query

```sql
SELECT name
FROM tablename
```

When I am trying to unload it using `UNLOAD` query from AWS Redshift, it is successfully finishing but giving weird quoting.

```
"name"
"tokenauthserver2018\
```

Here is my query

```sql
UNLOAD ($TABLE_QUERY$
SELECT name
FROM tablename
$TABLE_QUERY$)
TO 's3://bucket/folder'
MANIFEST VERBOSE HEADER DELIMITER AS ',' 
NULL AS '' ESCAPE GZIP ADDQUOTES ALLOWOVERWRITE PARALLEL OFF;
```

I tried unloading without `ADDQUOTES` as well, but got following data

```
name
"tokenauthserver2018
```

This is the query for above.

```sql
UNLOAD ($TABLE_QUERY$
SELECT name
FROM tablename
$TABLE_QUERY$)
TO 's3://bucket/folder'
MANIFEST VERBOSE HEADER CSV NULL AS '' GZIP ALLOWOVERWRITE PARALLEL OFF;
```

Comment: Mmm, looks like some strange characters in that field. If this is the only row & field causing you a problem, you could just replace the value with `UPDATE table SET name='tokenauthserver2018' WHERE name = '"tokenauthserver2018'` or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon support was able to resolve this, I am posting answer here for anyone interested.

This was due to presence of NULL character `\0` in my data. As I don't have control over source data, I used `TRANSLATE` function to replace `\0` character.

```
SELECT
TRANSLATE("name", CHR(0), '') AS "name"
FROM <tablename>
```

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TRANSLATE.html